# Age of Mythology: Extended Edition crashing on windows 10

Tags: steam, technical-issues, windows-10, age-of-mythology

I've had windows 10 since it's release, never ran into a problem with any game, I'd say every game has improved since. But for AoM:EE it runs for at least 30 minutes and then, when I click on a unit's description or upgrade armor,buildings,etc the games just shuts down. Most settings are set to default. Has anyone been able to find a fix for this issue?

Comment: Are you able to provide more information such as they hardware your running, is it through steam or standalone and if event viewer is posting anything also try running it in compatibility mode (win 7 mode)